# Adding a class with jQuery to parent element of a checkbox when that is clicked and the checkbox is hidden

Tags: jquery, checkbox, internet-explorer-8, html-lists

I have a list designed to look like toggle buttons, but they're actually a checklist of preferences.  As such, the input is hidden and I want to have a class added to the parent label if the checkbox is checked.

It all works great, except for in IE8 which isn't happy.  I think this may be the .change, but I can't quite work out how to achieve this with .click, my attempts have ended unsuccessfully.

[FIDDLE HERE!](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/yudUQ/)

HTML

```
<li>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" />
        <span class="btn-flat">Option</span>
    </label>
</li>
```

JS

```
$('.checkbox input').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).parent('.checkbox').addClass('checked');
        $(this).attr('checked','checked');
    }else {
        $(this).parent('.checkbox').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if this is checked, check it ?

```
if (this.checked) {
    $(this).attr('checked','checked');
}
```

doesn't make much sense, why not just :

```
$('.checkbox input').on('change', function() {
    $(this).parent('.checkbox').toggleClass('checked', this.checked);
});
```

and never ever remove the checked attribute, set it to false with `.prop('checked', false);` or `this.checked = false`

Comment: Thanks @adeneo.  I wasn't sure whether we needed that attribute explicitly there in the html, which is why I had, if it's checked, check it.  The code you've given is nice and clean which is great, only problem is it's still not working in IE8 for me?  Also, can you explain why you should never remove the checked attributed?  Just for my learning...

Comment: Not sure if removing the attribute does the same thing, but if you remove the checked property, it can never be checked again, you just broke it.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Any ideas about the IE issue?  I thought it may be to do with the .change instead of using .click possibly?

Comment: No, the change event should work fine in IE, so should the rest of that code ?

Comment: IE9> is fine, not IE8 though.

Comment: What version of jQuery ?

Comment: 1.9.1 - But as you mentioned before, why find something that is checked and check it.  I thought that attribute was needed to pass some data over on submit to say it was checked.  But, that not being the case, it's just about adding a class, and for that, using click on the .btn-flat element works in IE8.
`$('.checkbox .btn-flat').click(function(){
     $(this).parent('.checkbox').toggleClass('checked');
    });`

Answer (score 0):

try adding 
`$(this).parent().children('.btn-flat').addClass('grey');` to the if block and
 `$(this).parent().children('.btn-flat').removeClass('grey');` to the else block of the javascript and then add 
`.checkbox .grey{background-color: #ccc;}` 
to css file. This way it targets the specific html element.

Comment: The problem is that in IE8 the class is not being added, rather than the styles not coming through.

Comment: i've tested it on ie8 simulation. seems fine. are you testing it on a natively installed ie8?

Comment: I was simulating it too.  It's working now with this: `$('.checkbox .btn-flat').click(function(){ $(this).parent('.checkbox').toggleClass('checked'); });` Change function was causing me problems for some reason